# Bivariate Normal Distribution satisfying stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution

I am currently working on a Stochastic Process question for my Probability Course. I have hard time understanding how to show that a Bivariate Normal Distribution specifies a stochastic process. I am given:

$X_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_2\sim N(0,1).$

Then, $(X_1,X_2)\sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1, 1/2 \\ 1/2, 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$

As a result, my cdf is $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{(\pi \sqrt{3})} \exp( -\frac{2}{3}(x_1^2 - x_1x_2 + x_2^2))$

Does this specify a stochastic process with state space $S = R$, time domain $T = [1,2]$? Justify the answer.

From my lecture notes, I have the following:

i) $f(x) \geqslant 0$ almost everywhere

ii) Integral of $f(x)\,dx$ over $R^k$ is equal to 1.

If $f$ satisfies i and ii above, then $f$ is a density. Then by Kolmogorov    Consistency Theorem, we have that $f$ satisfies a stochastic process (everything marginalizes properly).

But then, where does $T = [1,2]$ come in?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Have a look at how to format posts [using MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ for mathematical expressions.

Comment: Done, thanks = D

Comment: No, thank you!.  I'm wondering if the *time domain* should be an interval, e.g. $[1,2]$ rather than $\{1,2\}$.  The discrete set notation $\{1,2\}$ suggests time can only take values $t=1,2$.

Comment: You have a good question. Looking back at lecture notes, T is written in terms of [] instead of {}.

http://www.utstat.utoronto.ca/mikevans/stac62/Ass22015.pdf

Comment: @AlexanderBrown The handwriting is a bit hard to read, but $T=\{1,2\}$ makes sense whereas $T=[1,2]$ does not.